# Hard coded path from .net core to angular

Tags: html, angular, asp.net-core

I want to pass hard coded path for pictures from backend to angular  src. Pictures stored in standard angular assets folder. When I use classic url in html everything works well.

```
<img class="external-system-picture" src='../../../../assets/img/logo/company-logo.png'>
```

but if change to use url property from backend like this:

```
<img class="external-system-picture" src='url'>

public string Url { get; set; } = "../../../../assets/img/logo/company-logo.png"
```

The picture can no load. Path is wrong..

Project has next structure:

```
Project:
  Backend
  Frontend
```

Comment: Try with `[src]="url"`

Comment: not metter. The same thing I think the problem path to picture when I call from backend but she is in angular/assets folder

Comment: [src]="url" or src="{{url}}". Anyway, I think that is simple "assets/img/logo/company-logo.png"

Answer (score 0):

The quare brackets on src property were problem. This is fixed problem.

```
<img class="external-system-picture" [src]='url'>
```